# this.router.navigate returns false

Tags: angular, routes

I'm trying to redirect the user to the previous road after they successfully log in.

My auth.guard.ts

```
    const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
    if (currentUser) {
      // logged in so return true
      return true;
    }

    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.router.navigate(['/login'], {queryParams: {returnUrl: state.url}});
    return false;
```

sets up the proper returnUrl

Then my login.component.ts

```
[...]
// get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
    this.route.queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
        this.returnUrl = params['redirectUrl'] || '/'
        console.log(this.returnUrl)
        console.log(params)
      } );

[...]

this.authenticationService.login(this.f.email.value, this.f.password.value)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          //TODO: navigate returns false
         this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]).then(nav => {
           console.log(nav); // true if navigation is successful
         }, err => {
           console.log(err) // when there's an error
         });
        },
        error => {
          this.spinner = false;
          this.submitted = false;
          this.invalid = true;
          this.loading = false;
        },
        () => {
          this.spinner = false;
          this.submitted = false;
        });
```

Here, the navigate returns false and does nothing else. 
I've tried to see if this.returnUrl is set correctly and indeed it is. So I don't know what can cause the issue. If I set this.router.navigate['/something'] then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

> login.component.ts

**In ngOnInit()**

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
   params => (this.returnUrl = params.return || '/')
);
```

Then

```
this.authenticationService.login(this.f.email.value, this.f.password.value)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
         this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        },
        error => {
          this.spinner = false;
          this.submitted = false;
          this.invalid = true;
          this.loading = false;
        } 
     });
```

Here you used **returnUrl** as your queryParam

`this.router.navigate(['/login'], {queryParams: {returnUrl: state.url}});`

But you trying to get **redirectUrl**

`params['redirectUrl']`

Change `params['redirectUrl']` to  `params['returnUrl']`

Comment: That didn't work.
I've noticed that whenever I put a variable in this.router.navigate[variable] it doesn't work. I can write an argument there, such as this.router.navigate['/home'] but if the same value is assigned to, let's say 'home', it won't work

Comment: no, 
If I console.log what happens with the navigation I'm getting 'false'

Comment: You used returnUrl as your queryParam. But you trying to get redirectUrl. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I see, I changed it to the proper values, just in case I also log out this.returnUrl, which gives a proper string. But despite it still doesn't work

Comment: You mean changed accordingly to what you updated or something else?

Comment: Yes, I did. It doesn’t work. I’m so surprised because it clearly should